Movie about a racist, mental breakdown
I saw this on TV in the early 1990s. It was a well-made film, starring a very well-known actor (whose face and name I cannot recall) who played a Southern racist married to a young woman. He killed a black child and was, to his bewilderment, charged with murder ("If there's a fine or something, just tell me and I'll pay it"). He began to believe his wife was trying to kill him and for some reason surrounded his bed with a glass floor (I don't remember what the reasoning was). The wife became close to the lawyer who was either defending or prosecuting the case, and at the end the protagonist killed the wife and lawyer; the latter via a shot in the crotch.  

Paris Trout
You can watch the complete movie here:



Dennis Hopper plays the Southern racist, Ed Harris is the lawyer.
The murder scene starts ca. at the 0:21:40 mark. Near the end of the movie, at the 1:35:10 mark Ed Harris is shot three times by Dennis Hopper, the third bullet goes into his lower abdomen.
Detailed plot:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris_Trout

"Paris Trout is an unrepentant racist in 1949 Georgia. The greedy and
  paranoid shopkeeper murders the sister of a black man who refuses to
  repay Trout’s IOU. When Trout is arrested for the crime, he is stunned
  and enraged, showing himself to be a man of the Old South. Lawyer
  Harry Seagraves arrives to calm the waters in court but is soon caught
  in crimes of his own, including a dangerous and doomed affair with
  Trout’s wife."


Thank you! Bits and pieces of the movie came back to me the other day and no amount of googling could find me the title

Please mark my answer as Best Answer. Thanks.

Not just upvote it, but there is also an option to mark it as Best Answer. :)
